# how to rearrange elements in a tensor, like in MATLAB?

Tags: tensorflow

For example, I got a tensor `[30,6,6,3]`: 30 is the `batch_size`, 6X6 is `height x width`, 3 is `channels`).

How could I rearrange its elements from every 3X3 to 1X9, like pixels in MATLAB? As the picture described:
[image]

`tf.reshape()` seems unworkable.

Comment: What do you mean with "unworkable"?

Comment: @JeroenHeier the array by tf.reshape(tensor,[1,1,9]) is not what i want.
i want every [1,6,6,3] to rearrange to [1,2,2,27], but tf.shape() is do the batch_size first,Its hard to describe, so i drew the picture. Really appreciate!

Comment: how do you do it in Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

You can do these kinds of transformations by using combination of transpose and reshape. Numpy and TensorFlow logic is the same, so here's a simpler example using numpy. Suppose you have 4x4 array and want to spit it into 4 sub-arrays by skipping rows/columns like in your example.

IE, starting with

```
a=array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

​
You want to obtain 4 sub-images like

```
[0, 2]
[8, 10]
```

and

```
[1, 3]
[9, 11]
```

etc

First you can generate subarrays by stepping over columns

```
b = a.reshape((4,2,2)).transpose([2,0,1])
```

This generates the following array

```
array([[[ 0,  2],
        [ 4,  6],
        [ 8, 10],
        [12, 14]],

       [[ 1,  3],
        [ 5,  7],
        [ 9, 11],
        [13, 15]]])
```

Now you skip the rows

```
c = b.reshape([2,2,2,2]).transpose(2,0,1,3)
```

This generates following array

```
array([[[[ 0,  2],
         [ 8, 10]],

        [[ 1,  3],
         [ 9, 11]]],


       [[[ 4,  6],
         [12, 14]],

        [[ 5,  7],
         [13, 15]]]])
```

Now notice that you have the desired subarrays, but the leftmost shape is 2x2, but you want to have 4, so you reshape

```
c.reshape([4,2,2])
```

which gives you

```
array([[[ 0,  2],
        [ 8, 10]],

       [[ 1,  3],
        [ 9, 11]],

       [[ 4,  6],
        [12, 14]],

       [[ 5,  7],
        [13, 15]]])
```

Note that the general technique of combining `n,m` array into `n*m` single dimension is to do `reshape(m*n, ...)`. Because of row-major order, the dimensions to flatten must be *on the left* for reshape to work as a flattening operation. So if in your example the channels are the last dimension, you will need to transpose them to the left, flatten (using reshape), and then transpose them back.